# Testing a django post view with curl

Tags: python, django, curl

I have the following POST method in django view.

```
def create_rule(request, rule_name, threshold, alert_value):
rule_name = request.GET.get('rule_name')
threshold = request.GET.get('threshold')
alert_value = request.GET.get('alert_value')
if request.method == 'POST' and rule_name is not None:
    user = get_current_user(request)
    rule = models.Rule(name=rule_name, user=user, threshold=threshold, 
                       alert_value=alert_value, is_internal=False)
    rule.save()
```

Now I am trying a curl from command line as follows:

`curl --data "rule_name=TOTAL_REQUESTS&threshold=2&alert_value=2" http://localhost:8000/rules/create/`

It throws an error telling.

`Exception Type: TypeError at /rules/create/
Exception Value: create_rule() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`

I am passing the arguments from curl . Why is that the post is not receiving those.

Comment: Not a good idea to create from a GET request. Actions that modify the database should be POST. (Imagine what happens if the Googlebot crawls your site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the parameters from the request, but you have also defined them as method arguments, you should remove them from the signature:

```
def create_rule(request):
    rule_name = request.GET.get('rule_name')
    threshold = request.GET.get('threshold')
    alert_value = request.GET.get('alert_value')
    if request.method == 'POST' and rule_name is not None:
        user = get_current_user(request)
        rule = models.Rule(name=rule_name, user=user, threshold=threshold, 
                       alert_value=alert_value, is_internal=False)
        rule.save()
```